# "The farthest reach" or "the farthest reaches"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

I heard on TV (an American science program, forgot the name of the program):

> We will venture out into **the farthest reaches** of the cosmos.

It makes me wonder if/when the noun "reach" is a count noun and can be pluralized. Bizarrely, according to [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/reach_2) and [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reach), it is either a noncount noun or a singular noun.

Google shows both terms are in use. For example, there is a book called **Farthest Reach**, but also instances of books and songs by the title **(the) Farthest Reaches** abound.

Google Ngram shows something interesting. The popularity of these two terms has changed over time:
[image]

So is **reach** also a count noun? And when should it be pluralized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When  **reach** refers to an extent, as in **the reach of his arm** or **the reach of this weapon**, it is countable and usually singular but can be used in the plural:

> What is the reach of this bow you're making out of carbon fiber, compared to a bow of the same weight made from yew?
>
> Let Larry try to get that can down from the back of that high shelf. He has the farthest reach.
>
> Great swimmers often have long reaches.
>
> Great swimmers often have a long reach.

When the meaning refers to a distant or remote place, whether literally or figuratively, it is typically in the plural:

> They traveled to  the farthest reaches of the taiga.
>
> They sought to explore the farthest reaches of the human mind.

Comment: So “farthest reach of the imagination” would be more idiomatic than “farthest reaches” because figuratively we’re stretching our imagination to its fullest extent, and not sending it off to a remote/inaccessible location, right?

Comment: @ColleenV: not really, it's just a different metaphor: mind-as-tool  (reach) and mind-as-terra-incognita (reaches).

Answer (score 2):

The pluralirity hinges on dimensionality. Space has directions (up, down, left, right, and many many more depending on how muxh credibility you put in string theory). The reach of a bow or swimmer is in one direction so won't be pluralised. Space; however, requires reaches into multiple directions/dimensions in order to span its coverage and so will be used pluralised (at least in a scientific or just scifi context where such thinking will dominate over the definition of a noun).